# error c2065: 'filename' : undeclared identifier

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <istream>
#include <ostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>    


void GetOutputFileStream(std::ofstream * fout, std::string filename);
void PrintStatistics(std::ostream & fout,
    int numUsed,
    int numNew,
    double newTotalPrice,
    double newTotalMileage,
    double usedTotalPrice,
    double usedTotalMileage);


int main()
{

double newTotalPrice = 33333;
double newTotalMileage = 44444;
double usedTotalPrice = 22222;
double usedTotalMileage = 99999;
int numUsed = 2;
int numNew = 3;
std::ofstream fout; // 'f'ile out - fout
std::string filename = "statistics.txt";
GetOutputFileStream(&fout, filename);
// Print to screen
PrintStatistics(std::cout,
    numUsed,
    numNew,
    newTotalPrice,
    newTotalMileage,
    usedTotalPrice,
    usedTotalMileage);
// Print to file
PrintStatistics(fout,
    numUsed,
    numNew,
    newTotalPrice,
    newTotalMileage,
    usedTotalPrice,
    usedTotalMileage);


std::cout << "Press ENTER to continue";
std::cin.get();

return 0;
}

void GetOutputFileStream(std::ofstream * fout, std::string filename)
{
    fout->open(filename, std::ios::out);
}
void PrintStatistics(std::ostream & fout,
int numUsed,
int numNew,
double newTotalPrice,
double newTotalMileage,
double usedTotalPrice,
double usedTotalMileage)
{

}
```

PrintStatistics is empty because I want to fix this error before beginning to write the function.

I keep receiving : error C2065: 'filename' : undeclared identifier

However, whenever I try testing GetOutputFileStream(&fout, filename); to make sure its functional using sample mechanics in int main() as shown below:

```
std::ofstream fout; // 'f'ile out - fout
std::string filename = "newFile.txt";
GetOutputFileStream(&fout, filename);
fout << "This is my new file!\n";
fout << "This is on a new line!";
fout.close();
```

I do not receive any errors and the function behaves as its suppose to. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thank you.

Comment: You're attempting to use GetOutputFileStream and PrintStatistics before you declare them. Is that your actual code?

Comment: [Compiles fine](http://cpp.sh/8oms) after putting `GetOutputFileStream` and `PrintStatistics` above `main()`. Is this really the code that is giving you the error that you mentioned?

Comment: The thing is, is that the sample code that I provided is what the instructor provided. We must obtain the same output as the instructor does using the sample code. Could the instructor just have arranged the sample code wrong or is there an error with my code? Thanks!

Comment: The functions are my code, the "sample" code provided in main() is what the instructor provided.

Comment: @alekbiz The issue here is that the code you provided does not produce the error that you say you are getting (`error c2065: 'filename' : undeclared identifier`). Please check and post the code that produces that error.

Comment: Oh gosh, I'm sorry. Let me fix the code really quick.

Comment: The code you have now [**Compiles Just Fine**](http://ideone.com/PeRyPF)

Comment: @Ben that's really strange. i still receive an error. someone mentioned this to me: 

"I would send in an "istream" argument into a function once, and everything worked good. But, on the next time, the function seemed to stop working. 
If this happens to you, consider this:
The "istream" incorporates error flag values that indicate it has reached the end of it's stream. 
Reseting the value of the these should correct the issue.
Look at some of the "istream" options here for more detail:  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/"

Comment: Yup, just as @Ben said, the code [compiles without errors](http://cpp.sh/9yu6p).

Comment: Could this error arise from consecutive uses, something to do with error flag values?

Comment: No, all that happens at run time. You are (apparently) getting a compilation error. They are unrelated.

Comment: @alekbiz The error you are now describing has nothing to do with the compilation of the code. You need a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Okay thanks for the help guys, I'll try to figure it out from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not `filename` that is causing you trouble. You dont define the following functions before you use them:

```
void GetOutputFileStream(std::ofstream * fout, std::string filename);
void PrintStatistics( ... );
```

You need to prototype them, or define them before they are used. [See here for more info.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prototype)

[Here are your actual compiler errors.](http://ideone.com/0hPC2v)

[And here is the same function with one way of fixing them.](http://ideone.com/Pb22sR)

Comment: Hey there, that was my mistake. My code calls the functions prior to main() i forgot to include it in my post. I've edited my code. Could you look over it again? Sorry.

Comment: @alekbiz Then there is nothing wrong with your code. The code in your question produces no error ....

Comment: I'll give you credit for the answer since you put in the effort to assist me and for directing me to what my problem may be.